# Customizing SqlErrorCodes

Tags: java, spring

I am facing a little problem - Customizing Oracle DB Error Codes.

I think it can be possible to map my error codes by :

- **adding "CustomSQLErrorCodesTranslation"**
- **adding "SQLErrorCodes" that registers "CustomSQLErrorCodesTranslation"**
- **adding "SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator", and set my "SqlErrorCodes"**

and get the "SQLErrorCodeSqlExceptionTranslator" object with DI, 
call the method **translate(String task, String sql, SQLException ex)**.

Here's my work.

```
<bean id="sqlExceptionTranslator" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator">
        <property name="sqlErrorCodes" ref="OracleSqlErrorCodes" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="OracleSqlErrorCodes" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodes">
        <property name="badSqlGrammarCodes">
            <value>900,903,904,917,936,942,17006</value>
        </property>
        <property name="invalidResultSetAccessCodes">
            <value>17003</value>
        </property>
        <property name="duplicateKeyCodes">
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataIntegrityViolationCodes">
            <value>1400,1722,2291,2292</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataAccessResourceFailureCodes">
            <value>17002,17447</value>
        </property>
        <property name="cannotAcquireLockCodes">
            <value>54</value>
        </property>
        <property name="cannotSerializeTransactionCodes">
            <value>8177</value>
        </property>
        <property name="deadlockLoserCodes">
            <value>60</value>
        </property>
        <property name="customTranslations">
            <list>
                <bean id="oracleCustomTranslations" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.CustomSQLErrorCodesTranslation">
                    <property name="errorCodes" value="12899" />
                    <property name="exceptionClass" value="com.musicovery.bookervery.db.exception.SampleException" />   
                </bean>             
            </list> 
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

in JAVA area,

```
@Test(expected=SampleException.class)
public void addMemberWithLongValue(){
    memberCommand1.setName("very very very very very very very very very long text");

    try{
        memberService.addMember(memberCommand1);
    }catch(DataAccessException e){


        SQLException sqlEx = new SQLException(e);

        DataAccessException dae = sqlExceptionTranslator.translate("task? what is it?", null, sqlEx);
        System.err.println("Derived from DataAccessException : " + dae.getClass().getName());

        throw dae;
    }

}
```

When running that code, the [redbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cymP1.jpg) is shown

It is no different whether error the mapping code is added or not.

When inserts data with too long value to Oracle DB, it returns the error code 12899.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)
```

I want to map the 12899 error code to a specific Exception class.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Besides, I am sorry my english is not good.

---

below contents are appended periodically to help you find the correct answer.

/////////////////////////////////
SampleException
/////////////////////////////////

```
package com.musicovery.bookervery.db.exception;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

public class SampleException extends DataAccessException{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SampleException(String msg, Throwable cause) {
        super(msg, cause);
        System.out.println("SampleException initialized");
    }
}
```

---

/////////////////////////////////
Edit - printStackTrace
/////////////////////////////////

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: task? what is it?; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

### The error may involve com.musicovery.bookervery.dao.MemberDao.addMember-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [12899]; ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

### The error may involve com.musicovery.bookervery.dao.MemberDao.addMember-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [12899]; ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at com.musicovery.bookervery.serviceTest.MemberServiceTest.addMemberWithLongValue(MemberServiceTest.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:21)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

### The error may involve com.musicovery.bookervery.dao.MemberDao.addMember-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [12899]; ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

    at com.musicovery.bookervery.serviceTest.MemberServiceTest.addMemberWithLongValue(MemberServiceTest.java:85)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

### The error may involve com.musicovery.bookervery.dao.MemberDao.addMember-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [12899]; ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:71)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:346)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:231)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:59)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.addMember(Unknown Source)
    at com.musicovery.bookervery.service.MemberServiceImpl.addMember(MemberServiceImpl.java:17)
    at com.musicovery.bookervery.serviceTest.MemberServiceTest.addMemberWithLongValue(MemberServiceTest.java:82)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "MUSICOVERY"."MEMBERS"."NAME" (actual: 54, maximum: 12)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3488)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:22)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:29)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:43)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:121)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:338)
    ... 37 more
```

---

I checked what error code the exception has.

```
SQLException sqlEx = new SQLException(e);           
System.out.println("sqlEx error code : " + sqlEx.getErrorCode());
```

Console :

```
sqlEx error code : 0
```

Why is it 0? it should be 12899.

---

I am developing with MyBatis. I read the [getting started documentation](http://mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html)
And that APIs seems like doesn't throw any exception. so i guess sql error code  is 0.

---

Please tell me any source you want, I will edit this article.

Comment: Probably you can extend from org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException and have a exception class for "ValueTooLarge"

Comment: Can you try to check whether the `dae` variable is actually the instance of the `SampleException` ? I think the problem might be when the spring try to instantiate the custom exception. Is it possible to post the log here?

Comment: No, 'dae' is not the instance of the 'SampleException' .'dae' is came from org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I delivered wrong exception to translator.

```
SQLException sqlEx = new SQLException(e);
```

It should be like

```
SQLException sqlEx = (SQLException)e.getCause();
// System.out.println("exception code : " + sqlEx.getErrorCode());
```